# Scalding flatMap tuple containing list

Tags: scala, scalding

I have the following input tuple that I'd like to flatMap: `(String, List[String])`

E.G. Input:

```
("a", ["1", "2"])
("b", ["3", "4"])
```

Needed output:

```
("a", "1")
("a", "2")
("b", "3")
("b", "4")
```

Is there an elegant way to do this in Scalding/Scala?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a multi-line `for ... yield` expression:

```
for {
  (a, bs) <- tupleList
  b <- bs
} yield (a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

May not be the best solution but cascading maps and then flatting the result was the best i can come up with.

Awsome thing about FP is that you can do the same thing in very very different ways. Hope someone posts a different solution

```
val input = List( ("a", List("1", "2")), ("b", List("3","4")))

val output = input.map(it => it._2.map { (it._1, _)}).flatten
```

As indicated the output can change to

```
input.flatMap(tuple => tuple._2.map { (tuple._1 , _) })
```

Comment: No need to flatten if you flatMap.